Changing spacing after paragraph command in memoir to inter-sentence spacing?
I'm using memoir to produce a document. I noticed that the spaces after \paragraph produced by the default value of \setafterparaskip of -1.0em are larger than what looks good to me, especially for incomplete lines before an equation:

I know that I can change the spacing using, e.g., \setafterparaskip{-0.6em}. It seems appropriate to change it to the inter-sentence spacing of LaTeX, so that it can stretch and shrink, but I have not been able to find the corresponding name or value. So my question is: How do I set the spacing after paragraphs to the inter-sentence spacing?

Use the relevant font parameters.
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setafterparaskip{-\fontdimen2\font plus -\fontdimen3\font minus -\fontdimen4\font}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Hello there.} \lipsum[1][1-6]

\paragraph{Hello again.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit
\[
a^2+b^2=c^2
\]

\end{document}


